# How does $[x+y+z]=[x+y]+[z+\langle y+x\rangle]$ holds?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For any real number $x$, let $[x]$ denote the largest integer less than or equal to $x$ and $\langle x\rangle=x-[x],$ that is the fractional part of $x$. For arbitrary real numbers $x,y$ and $z$, then $[x+y+z]=[x+y]+[z+\langle y+x\rangle]$ .

How is it derived? I tried some numbers, but how does that hold in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's cut down on the clutter here. Substitute $x+y=t$. Our equation is

$$[t+z]=[t]+[z+<t>]$$

Now obviously, $$[t+z]=[[t]+<t>+z]$$

also, if $k$ is an integer, then

$$[x+k]=[x]+k$$

Here, $k=[t]$.

Q.E.D.